# Android 5.0.2 Out of memory error using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android app I have a table that is filled using an AsyncTask (in real life it is doing a lot more than just a few text views, but the problem can be seen with this reduced code as well):

```
private class RowPainter extends AsyncTask<Statistics, Void, Void>
{
    private final WeakReference<TableRow> rowReference;

    public RowPainter(TableRow row)
    {
        rowReference = new WeakReference<>(row);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Statistics... statistics)
    {
        fillDetailsRow(statistics[0]);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        rowReference.clear();
    }

    private void fillDetailsRow(Statistics stats)
    {
        fillText(R.id.name, stats.name, rowReference);
        fillText(R.id.level, printableValue(stats.level), rowReference);
        fillText(R.id.total_count, printableValue(stats.TotalCount), rowReference);
        fillText(R.id.track_score, printableValue(stats.calculateScore()), rowReference);
    }
    private void fillText(int viewId, String text, WeakReference<TableRow> reference)
    {
        TableRow row = reference.get();
        if (row == null)
            return;

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(viewId);
        textView.setText(text);
    }
    private String printableValue(int value)
    {
        return value == 0 ? "" : String.format("%,d", value);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy SIII phone with Android 4.4, but on my new Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 5.0.2 it produces out of memory errors after I rotate device 3-4 times (I can rotate my SIII dozens of times with no problem). When I watch memory monitor in Android Studio while running on SIII - my memory stays under 64MB at all times, but S6 Edge... - it starts at 64Mb and every time I rotate the device it adds about 30-40Mb and never goes down. I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Why are you updating the UI in `doInBackground`?

Comment: Well not only why. As that would crash the app immediately.

Comment: Actually at the time when this AsyncTask is running the row is not part of UI yet and the app is not crashing at all (it is being created and will be added to the table inside onPostExecute method. As I have mentioned, this is just a fragment of the whole thing). The only problem is that on newer phone memory is never released and eventually I am getting out of memory errors.

Comment: Another note: I am actually doing all my UI updates in doInBackground (in other parts of my app), so the UI stays responsive while I am doing all my work. And nothing is crashing... I think, this is the main idea behind AsyncTask - be able to do all my work (UI included) while main thread is responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I know the answer to my question. I tested my app on different devices with Android 5 and some of them work fine while others get OutOfMemory errors very soon. I have switched my code from using AsyncTasks to use Runnable - and everything is back to normal. No more weird out of memory errors, runnable does its job and is releasing memory like it is supposed to.